# Mass onLoad event freezes gif animation

Tags: jquery, onload, jquery-events

I trying to make trivial load indicator, but in this case I'm stuck...

What we have

1. `#submit` button
2. when `onClick` to `#submit`, we fetch `getJSON`
3. JSON data - is urls of images (might be 1-1000++ urls)
4. for `.each` src we check `onLoad`
5. and if its loaded we `.append` html to div `#out`

   ```
   <img id="load" src="load.gif" />
   <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
   <div id="out"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">

   $('#submit').click(function()
   {
       $.getJSON('/data.json', function(data) {

           $.each(data, function(idx, img_src) {

               $('<img src="'+img_src+'">').load(function() {
                   $('#out').append('<img id="id'+idx+'" src="'+img_src+'">');
               });     

           });

       });

   });
   ```

In my example I don't show/hide load.gif,
nvm for now, it shows the main problem - animation freezes when script works.

Tested on jQuery 1.7.1 + Chrome 17 (my app special for this browser)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give the browser some cycles to do other things while loading a zillion images, you can do a small amount of work on a series of `setTimeout()` calls to allow some other things to happen between your chunks of work like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $.getJSON('/data.json', function(data) {
        var i = 0;
        var out$ = $('#out'); 
        function appendNextImage() {
            // assumes data is an array of image URLs
            $('<img id="id'+i+'" src="'+data[i]+'">').load(function() {
                out$.append(this);
            });
            i++;
            if (i < data.length) {
                setTimeout(appendNextImage, 1);
            }
        }
        appendNextImage();
    });
});
```

I also changed your image creation so you append the DOM object that you've already created rather than making a second duplicate DOM object and put the `$('#out')` jQuery object in a closure so it isn't recreated every time.

Since I can't use jQuery's `.each()` in this coding structure, I had to manually iterate through your data.  I assumed that it's an array of URLs.